# Magento 2 Category URL?

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to find the URL directly to categories - I use Megamenu but I've tried everything I can find but keep getting 404 errors

For this example let's assume im trying to get the link to 'Furniture' category which contains active products, the direct link to the product works fine using domain.com/my-main-product.html

I've tried

```
http://example.com/furniture
http://example.com/catalog/furniture
http://example.com/catalog/category/view/id/143
```

Can anyone recommend how I can find them please - my layout currently is:

```
Default Category
   Furniture
   Test Category
```

All I get is 'Page doesnt exist' (404)

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following path.

`{select category}--> search engine optimization-->url key.`

You can see the URL there. When you visit you should append `.html` to the URL. For example, if the value is `furniture` your URL should be like this

`http://example.com/furniture.html`

or

`http://example.com/index.php/furniture.html` (*if mod_rewrite is not enabled*)